# Format raw problem

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

recently I faced strange error with raw format:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=44&Itemid=80&format=raw
```

**Error 500:**

```
View not found [name, type, prefix]: category,raw,contentView
```

I googled for this problem, but actually did not find the correct answer for this... 
So what is wrong with that ?

Joomla version: 1.5.21

Your help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try adding a view to your component e.g. view.raw.php